# How to use remote attribute in entity framework classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In my application I am creating my EDMX file using Database First Method.

I get classes generated for all of tables there.

I am able to use annotations like Required,Display,StringLength,RegularExpression,etc. there.

I know in my model of MVC I can use annotation named "Remote" by which I can validate my entity property.

Is there any way to use this "Remote" attribute in entity classes ? or may some other way to create custom annotation?

Update:
I have ViewModel Like this

```
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public TestInfo Test { get; set; }
```

Both Exam & TestInfo are entity classes generated by entity framework.

There is property "ExamName" in entity class "Exam" which I want to validate for duplicate names.

Comment: take a look here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx

Comment: I saw that but that is implemented in Model in MVC project. I want to implement same kind of thing where my entity classes are generated using entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

`Remote` is a data annotation used to validate an input user enters in UI. It makes an ajax call to one of your action method (which you can specify) and expects a result value which tells whether this data already exists in your system.

You probably need to create a new view model for your view, instead of using the entity class created by entity framework, for your view. then you can have `Remote` attribute on that. In your action method ,you may deal with the actual entities to check the existence of the data.

```
public class RegisterVM
{
    [Required]  
    [Remote("IsAvailable", "Validation")]      
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you may have your `IsAvailable` action method to check the UserName exists or not.  Also make sure now your Register viw is strongly typed to this new RegisterVM viewmodel.

```
@model RegisterVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  // your form controls

}
```

It does not makes sense to have `Remote` attribute on an Entity class. It should be on a view model.Otherwise you are mixing things up!

Comment: I want to do it in my entity class. Not in ViewModel

Comment: Why do you want to do it in your entity class ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: i am trying to find if name already exists or not. If exists then It should give error.

Comment: So use the view model and in your `IsAvailable` action method you may query the orginal Entities to check whether it exists or not.

Comment: I have viewmodel where I am using many entities. So I cant do it there.

Comment: If you leave it to the entity layer, then you could have your code creating what are valid models, which then interact with all sorts of other objects before being rejected by the entity layer.

Comment: @vaibhavshah The Remote attribute also specifies what endpoint the validation method lives at. Doesn't make sense (imo) to put that on the model. The model shouldn't be concerned with that. Viewmodel seems much better.

Comment: Use simple POCO as your viewmodel instead of using entity classes as your viewmodel's property. Have a mapping layer which maps your viewmodel to entity. Currently you are making a tight coupling between your viewmodels and entities. What if you decide to use a web service as source of your data. ?

Comment: I have partial classes of entity classes where I perform all validations. Can I do validation there ?